# How can I verify that the retries have been exhausted in my ExchangeFilterFunction?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-test

I am executing a ExchangeFilterFunction whose purpose is to serve as a global retry mechanism for our `WebClient`. The filter is defined here

```java
@Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
        return next.exchange(request)
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> Mono.just(clientResponse)
                        .filter(response -> {
                                    final HttpStatusCode code = clientResponse.statusCode();
                                    boolean isRetryable = Boolean.FALSE;
                                    if (code.isError()) {
                                        //check if its a retryable error
                                        isRetryable = Arrays.stream(DEFAULT_RETRYABLE_ERROR_CODES).anyMatch(defaultCode -> defaultCode == code.value()) ||
                                                (retryFilterConfiguration.getRetryErrorCodes() != null &&
                                                        retryFilterConfiguration.getRetryErrorCodes().stream().anyMatch(retryErrorCode -> retryErrorCode == code.value()));
                                        LOGGER.warn("Request Failed.  Retrying -> url={}; status={}", request.url(), code.value());
                                    }
                                    return isRetryable;
                                }
                        ).flatMap(response -> clientResponse.createException())
                        .flatMap(Mono::error)
                        .thenReturn(clientResponse)
                ).retry(retryFilterConfiguration.getRetryCount());
    }
```

I have written a unit test that is intended to test that the retries have expired. The test is successful at verifying that the error occurred, but I am unable to verify the number of retries that were taken. I can tell that the retry occurred by looking at the logs, but I am unsure how to verify that programmatically.

```java
    @DisplayName("Retry on Default Error Code")
    @Test
    public void defaultRetryableErrorCode(){
        //ARRANGE
        int retryCount = 2;
        int tooManyRequestsErrorCode = HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value();
        ClientRequest mockRequest = mock(ClientRequest.class);
        ExchangeFunction mockNext = mock(ExchangeFunction.class);
        ClientResponse mockResponse = mock(ClientResponse.class);
        when(mockNext.exchange(mockRequest)).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockResponse));
        when(mockResponse.statusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(tooManyRequestsErrorCode))
                .thenReturn(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(tooManyRequestsErrorCode))
                .thenReturn(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(tooManyRequestsErrorCode));
        when(retryFilterConfiguration.getRetryCount()).thenReturn(retryCount);
        //ACT
        Mono<ClientResponse> clientResponseMono = retryStrategyFilter.filter(mockRequest,mockNext);
        //ASSERT
        StepVerifier.create(clientResponseMono)
                .verifyError();
    }
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I unit test an ExchangeFilterFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76302491/how-can-i-unit-test-an-exchangefilterfunction)

Comment: @Numichi - Not quite. I'm able to unit test the exchange filter function, but I would like to know how I can test that the retries were exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the retry policy configured and the test setup, I'm assuming we are expecting the `exchange` method to be invoked twice, as this would retry the call.

If so, we can use the `verify` method from Mockito to verify a specific method on a mocked object is called a specific amount of times - [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4)

```
verify(mockNext, times(2)).exchange(mockRequest);
```